# UPDATING database after SELECT on the php site

Tags: php, html, sql, select

I tried to do the php site where you can chose component from select. Selected component should be returned by SELECT from database. Next you can change values from this table by UPDATE. The last record in every row is an input where is displayed price of the component and the button(input submit). My problem is how to use this button to set value in input and update the table. Below are screen shots of my database and site. I tried a lot of things and now i can this:

```
    <form method="GET" action="sklep2.php">
    <font>Lista aktualnie dostępnych podzespołów</font>
<select id="selekt" name="selekt">
    <option value="1">Procesory</option>
    <option value="2">Ram</option>
    <option value="5">Karty graficzne</option>
    <option value="6">Dyski</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="zatwierdź" name="submit">
    <table id="tabela">
    <tr id="first"><td>NAZWA PODZESPOŁU</td><td>OPIS</td><td>CENA</td></tr>
    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sklep');
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $typy_id = $_GET['selekt'];
    $sql = "SELECT nazwa, opis, cena, id FROM podzespoly WHERE typy_id = $typy_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo '<form action="sklep2.php" method="GET">';
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<tr><td>'.$row['nazwa'].'</td><td>';
            echo $row['opis'].'</td><td>';
            echo '<input id="new_price" type="number" value="'.$row['cena'].'">';
            echo '<input style="display:none" id="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
            echo '<input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1">';           
        }
    }
    echo '</form>';
    if(isset($_GET['submit1'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $price = $_GET['new_price'];
        $upd = "UPDATE podzespoly SET cena = $price WHERE id = $id";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $upd)) {                  
                echo "successfully updated";
                          }
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn)
    ?>
    </table>
    </form>
```

[My php site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKlXu.png)
[My Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdJ54.png)

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize your queries and use prepared statements. Your `input`s are missing `name`s... Also a `form` in a `form` might cause issues.

Comment: @user3783243 A form inside a form _does_ cause issues. Nested forms are not allowed in HTML. The inner form simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter mentioned, forms within forms aren't allowed. But also, it's a structure designed to confuse. It also seems that you are confusing your presentation from your functionality.

Both of your forms point to the same endpoint, also a recipe for confusion.

Suggestion: get your site working with the HTML static, before introducing PHP variables you need.

Suggestion: research PDO and SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. I changed my code and now it is better. When I try to change value in input, only the last row is working. I don't know why but I think that it is because

```
$row['id']
```

is in the loop. I have no idea what I can change to update values in every rows.

```
<form method="GET" action="sklep2.php">
<font>Lista aktualnie dostępnych podzespołów</font><select id="selekt" name="selekt">
<option value="1">Procesory</option>
<option value="2">Ram</option>
<option value="5">Karty graficzne</option>
<option value="6">Dyski</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="zatwierdź" name="submit">
<table id="tabela">
<tr id="first"><td>NAZWA PODZESPOŁU</td><td>OPIS</td><td>CENA</td></tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sklep');
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
$typy_id = $_GET['selekt'];
$sql = "SELECT nazwa, opis, cena, id FROM podzespoly WHERE typy_id = $typy_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row['nazwa'].'</td><td>';
        echo $row['opis'].'</td><td>';
        echo '<input id="new_price" type="number" name="new_price" value="'.$row['cena'].'">';
        echo '<input style="display:block" id="id" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
        echo '<input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1">';           
    }
}
}

if(isset($_GET['submit1'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $price = $_GET['new_price'];
    $upd = "UPDATE podzespoly SET cena = $price WHERE id = $id";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $upd)) {                  
            echo "successfully updated";
                      }
                      }


mysqli_close($conn)
?>
```